# How to fill a Bezier Curve and reduce its vertices

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, faces

I'm doing a model and there is a part on the clothes that I think is easier to do with curves (the one marked with red) but after using the curves tool to draw the figure, I can't find an option to fill the faces. Is it an addon or option to do it or it is done manually?[image: First image]

Also if I convert the curve into a mesh, select all the vertices and fill with F, it almost fixes the problem, but the mesh will have a lot of vertices and it makes difficult to work with all of them, also if I add a subdivision modifier it will lag the app. How can I avoid the creation of a great amount of vertices? [image: Vertices]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fill a curve it needs to be 2D (so it will need to be flat on Z) and also choose a fill mode. Also the *Resolution Preview U* value will determine the number of vertices once converted:

[image]

But if you've already converted it into a mesh you can select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* and tweak the *Max Angle* value in the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view):

[image]